# getting media url from json string

Tags: iphone, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

How would I get the image path+name out of this json?

```
    /*
     {
     distance = 0;
     "effective_from" = "2011-02-19 12:27:20";
     "effective_thru" = "2011-02-19 13:27:20";
     fname = eric;
     latitude = "11.92179";
     "listing_id" = 60;
     lname = cartman;
     longitude = "-74.70189";
     lstatus = active;
     media = "{\"media\":
     [
     {\"id\":149,\"media_url\":\"mediauploads/149.jpg\"},
     {\"id\":150,\"media_url\":\"mediauploads/150.jpg\"},
     {\"id\":151,\"media_url\":\"mediauploads/151.jpg\"},
     {\"id\":152,\"media_url\":\"mediauploads/152.jpg\"}
     ]}";
     tags = "Separate multiple tags with commas";
     text = "Listing text";
     title = "Please provide a descriptive title";
     username = eric;
     "users_id" = 13;
     },
     */
```

My problem is that NSDictionary *media = [userContent objectForKey:@"media"]; returns a -[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x66662a0 so I cannot get the Array out of it.

Update: so it turns out that I get as a string from the server. How can I parse it to a dictionary?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) provides a JSON Deserializer class that contains a method to convert JSON to a dictionary.

If you get the JSON back as a string, firstly convert it to NSData. For example:

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
```

Then create a CJSONDeserializer and pass the data to return a dictionary:

```
CJSONDeserializer *deserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
error = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [deserializer deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
```

You should then be able to extract your required data from the dictionary.

Comment: I ended up using NSString *media = [userContent objectForKey:@"media"]; and NSDictionary *imageDict = [media JSONValue]; since I do not want to add another json src to my project. Not sure if it is even possible/recommened. Thank you for your answer, I will accept it.